# ¿como puedo manipular elementos traídos de ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Verán mi problema es este, estoy tratando de manipular una clase que de una etiqueta article que inserta por medio de ajax, el problema es que no lo puedo manipular ya que eso se agrega después de que se carga la pagina

¿hay alguna manera de poder resolver esto?

se los agradecería mucho.

les dejo un ejemplo de como trate de hacerlo

explico mi problema mas a detalle:

stoy tratando de tener la contabilización de todos los que tengan esa clase, pero el problema es que estoy utilizando un plug-in que carga esa clase que necesito en un ajax, por lo cual no me deja manipular el elemento y por lo tanto no me hace la contabilización.

esta pregunta es diferente a la que pregunte anteriormente ya que este problema me surgio a raiz de que se descubrio que esa clase que quiero contabilizar la inserta por medio de ajax por lo cual me salio esta nueva incognita ya que no la puedo manipular

```
var numElem =$('article.tg-item-hidden').length;

alert(numElem);
```

dejo mi html donde tengo problemas

```
<div id="grid-profesional">
<!-- The Grid Plugin Version 2.6.0 --><!-- The Grid Wrapper Start -->
<div class="tg-grid-wrapper tg-txt full-height tg-grid-loaded" id="grid-6966" data-version="2.6.0"><!-- The Grid Styles -->
  <div class="tg-grid-holder tg-layout-grid" style="left: -3px; width: 1425px; position: relative; height: 195px;">
    <!-- The Grid item #1 -->
    <article class="tg-item tg-post-1873 tg-profesional f111 f12 f8 f7 f110 f22 f45 f70 f40 tg-item-hidden" data-row="1" data-col="1" style="width: 195px; height: 195px; position: absolute; display: none;">
      <div class="tg-item-inner">
        <div class="tg-item-media-holder tg-light">
          <div class="tg-item-media-inner">
            <div class="tg-item-image" style="background-image: url(http://embajadorestec.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/a879cc_1081cca149a74525ad13b7cf759e331b~mv2_d_1538_1923_s_2-320x320.jpg)"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="tg-item-media-content ">
            <div class="tg-item-overlay"></div>
            <div class="tg-top-holder"><span class="tg-item-meta-data tg-element-1"><a target="_self" href="http://embajadorestec.com/usuario/juanpablosanchez/">NEGOCIOS</a></span><h2 class="tg-item-title tg-element-2"><a target="_self" href="http://embajadorestec.com/usuario/juanpablosanchez/">Juan Pablo Sánchez</a></h2></div><div class="tg-bottom-holder"><span class="tg-item-meta-data tg-element-5"><a target="_self" href="http://embajadorestec.com/usuario/juanpablosanchez/">Primer Semestre</a></span><span class="tg-item-meta-data tg-element-4"><a target="_self" href="http://embajadorestec.com/usuario/juanpablosanchez/">Hidalgo</a></span></div></div></div></div></article>
    <!-- The Grid item #2 -->
    <article class="tg-item tg-post-4704 tg-profesional f112 f12 f8 f7 f46 f110 f22 f47 f45 f70 f40" data-row="1" data-col="1" style="width: 195px; height: 195px; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; transition-property: opacity, transform; transition-duration: 2060ms;"><div class="tg-item-inner"><div class="tg-item-media-holder tg-light"><div class="tg-item-media-inner"><div class="tg-item-image" style="background-image: url(http://embajadorestec.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/Tiffany_Fondo_grid-320x320.jpg)"></div></div><div class="tg-item-media-content "><div class="tg-item-overlay"></div><div class="tg-top-holder"><span class="tg-item-meta-data tg-element-1"><a target="_self" href="http://embajadorestec.com/usuario/tiffany/">LAEt</a></span><h2 class="tg-item-title tg-element-2"><a target="_self" href="http://embajadorestec.com/usuario/tiffany/">Tiffany Thalia Corona</a></h2></div><div class="tg-bottom-holder"><span class="tg-item-meta-data tg-element-5"><a target="_self" href="http://embajadorestec.com/usuario/tiffany/">Sexto Semestre</a></span><span class="tg-item-meta-data tg-element-4"><a target="_self" href="http://embajadorestec.com/usuario/tiffany/">Hidalgo</a></span></div></div></div></div></article>
          <!-- The Grid item #3 --><article class="tg-item tg-post-4135 tg-profesional f112 f12 f107 f8 f7 f46 f110 f22 f70 f40 f50" data-row="1" data-col="1" style="width: 195px; height: 195px; position: absolute; left: 205px; top: 0px; transition-property: opacity, transform; transition-duration: 2060ms;"><div class="tg-item-inner"><div class="tg-item-media-holder tg-light"><div class="tg-item-media-inner"><div class="tg-item-image" style="background-image: url(http://embajadorestec.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/Ixchel_Fondo_grid-320x320.jpg)"></div></div><div class="tg-item-media-content "><div class="tg-item-overlay"></div><div class="tg-top-holder"><span class="tg-item-meta-data tg-element-1"><a target="_self" href="http://embajadorestec.com/usuario/ixchel/">LDP</a></span><h2 class="tg-item-title tg-element-2"><a target="_self" href="http://embajadorestec.com/usuario/ixchel/">Ixchel Alondra León</a></h2></div><div class="tg-bottom-holder"><span class="tg-item-meta-data tg-element-5"><a target="_self" href="http://embajadorestec.com/usuario/ixchel/">Segundo Semestre</a></span><span class="tg-item-meta-data tg-element-4"><a target="_self" href="http://embajadorestec.com/usuario/ixchel/">Hidalgo</a></span></div></div></div></div></article>
          <!-- The Grid item #4 --><article class="tg-item tg-post-4697 tg-profesional f112 f12 f8 f7 f46 f110 f22 f43 f70 f40 f48" data-row="1" data-col="1" style="width: 195px; height: 195px; position: absolute; left: 410px; top: 0px; transition-property: opacity, transform; transition-duration: 2060ms;"><div class="tg-item-inner"><div class="tg-item-media-holder tg-light"><div class="tg-item-media-inner"><div class="tg-item-image" style="background-image: url(http://embajadorestec.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/Kevin_Fondo_grid-320x320.jpg)"></div></div><div class="tg-item-media-content "><div class="tg-item-overlay"></div><div class="tg-top-holder"><span class="tg-item-meta-data tg-element-1"><a target="_self" href="http://embajadorestec.com/usuario/kevinbarrera/">ITIt</a></span><h2 class="tg-item-title tg-element-2"><a target="_self" href="http://embajadorestec.com/usuario/kevinbarrera/">Kevin Barrera</a></h2></div><div class="tg-bottom-holder"><span class="tg-item-meta-data tg-element-5"><a target="_self" href="http://embajadorestec.com/usuario/kevinbarrera/">Sexto Semestre</a></span><span class="tg-item-meta-data tg-element-4"><a target="_self" href="http://embajadorestec.com/usuario/kevinbarrera/">Hidalgo</a></span></div></div></div></div></article>
          <!-- The Grid item #5 --><article class="tg-item tg-post-1871 tg-profesional f111 f12 f8 f7 f110 f22 f45 f70 tg-item-hidden" data-row="1" data-col="1" style="width: 195px; height: 195px; position: absolute; display: none;"><div class="tg-item-inner"><div class="tg-item-media-holder tg-light"><div class="tg-item-media-inner"><div class="tg-item-image" style="background-image: url(http://embajadorestec.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/a879cc_45ac8bd3c7a847fc876717d363725a9f~mv2_d_1517_1896_s_2-320x320.jpg)"></div></div><div class="tg-item-media-content "><div class="tg-item-overlay"></div><div class="tg-top-holder"><span class="tg-item-meta-data tg-element-1"><a target="_self" href="http://embajadorestec.com/usuario/danielortega/">NEGOCIOS</a></span><h2 class="tg-item-title tg-element-2"><a target="_self" href="http://embajadorestec.com/usuario/danielortega/">Daniel Ortega</a></h2></div><div class="tg-bottom-holder"><span class="tg-item-meta-data tg-element-5"><a target="_self" href="http://embajadorestec.com/usuario/danielortega/">Primer Semestre</a></span><span class="tg-item-meta-data tg-element-4"><a target="_self" href="http://embajadorestec.com/usuario/danielortega/">Hidalgo</a></span></div></div></div></div></article></div></div><!-- The Grid Wrapper End --> 
</div>
```

Comment: para poder apoyarte en tus dudas es ideal que muestres tu avance y la parte en la que estás teniendo dificultades, saludos.

Comment: listo , aqui puse mi avance, como veras, estoy tratando de tener la contabilización de todos los que tengan esa clase, pero el problema es que estoy utilizando un plug-in que carga esa clase que necesito en un ajax, por lo cual no me deja manipular el elemento y por lo tanto no me hace la contabilización

Comment: no esta duplicado, me dijeron que mi otra pregunta ya estaba resuelta y como ya tuve otra nueva duda, me tenia que formular otra pregunta, ya que ya vi que no me estaba haciendo lo que queria porque llamada esa clase por ajax.

saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes intentar utilizando el método ready de jQuery, este hace que el código que esta dentro de la función se ejecute después de cargar todos los elementos del DOM.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
var numElem =$('article.tg-item-hidden').length;

alert(numElem); 
});
```

Comment: hola, todo eso si lo tenia encerrado en un .ready pero aun asi no